# Can a Pi 4 manage a home surveillance network of 4 or 5 FHD cameras?

Tags: networking, pi-4

I need to set up a CCTV system for my home on the other side of the world as it's near a sketchy stretch of the alley that I can monitor from here. I need at least 4 to cover 4 sides and possibly a fifth one which can be rotated to cover for any blind spots.
It doesn't need to be like motion-sensitive type as I know the time they come near my property but it doesn't hurt.

So,

1. Can a raspberry pi zero w + pi infrared cam module work as the camera?
2. Is it possible for a pi 4 to host that network?
3. Would regular wifi-enabled cameras work in that network, instead of the pi zero w based one?
4. Can I hide the camera network broadcasting the id?

Sorry to ask so many questions! I'm just starting my Soft. Engg. course very late(after having a wonderful career in Mech. Engg.) and getting to grips with things!

Thank you so much!
Have a good BF2021 and holidays!!!

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes
2. Yes
3. Yes with the correct software on your Pi 4
4. Not sure what you mean by this

Have a look at MotionEyeOS for your Pi4, this works well with both Pi zero W and other network cameras. I have a Pi4 8gb running MotionEyeOS and currently hosting a Pi zero camera, a Pi 3 camera, 2 network cameras and an ESP32 Cam. I assume you have internet and WiFi etc at your remote home ?

Comment: @Bra1n I’m interested in what the load is like on the pi4 running a network like that. Is it a “full time job”, or any rough estimate of what the load is per camera added?

Comment: Here's  snapshot I just took, bear in mind I boot mine from an SSD which helps a lot. Motion Detection is probably the biggest cpu tasker but in my case the Pi 3 and Pi zero are doing their own so this Pi is doing the other 3.
Mem: 7051128K used, 961596K free, 252K shrd, 166676K buff, 6305248K cached
CPU:  55% usr   3% sys   0% nic  40% idle   0% io   0% irq   0% sirq
Load average: 2.23 2.39 2.38 4/138 20736

Comment: OP here! Thanks for the answers Bra1n.! Now here are some follow-up comments from my side.  1. Can it also communicate stepper motor for like rotating the assembly?   2. Your follow-up comment clarifies my doubts too. But it's still mindboggling what things a tiny computer can do.  3. Cool!  4. Now, I'm thinking like this, use ethernet to connect to pi 4. Pi 4 creates a wifi network that has the cameras connected and with the SSID hidden, it can't be detected easily, right? Would it be possible? Or I would have to connect the cameras and the pi 4 to the home network directly?

Comment: If you follow my suggestion of using MotionEyeOS this is a specially cutdown version of the Pi OS dedicated to running the cameras so whilst it is capable of running scripts for certain events like motion detection it won't be doing much else so I'd forget the stepper motor control and acting as a WiFi access point. I use my home network which you're going to need to use anyway for remote access. I'd be more worried about physical access to the cameras rather than a WiFi hacker. Hiding the SSID isn't a security measure at all. just use up to date encryption and a strong passphrase.

Comment: Thanks once again Bra1n. I'll check it out and try to get a pi zero w+camera and a Pi 4 to understand how it works.